# How can I update a variable using Observable without render DOM in Angular 2, like a real-time page

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2 + and need to create a page in real time. When I load my component, I call a service using Observable and I save the result in a variable that I use in a ngFor in my model. After loading it, I need to refresh the data every minute and need to refine the changed data.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start with **Observable interval**  it will do polling for every minute.

service

```
poll{
     return Observable
            .interval(1000)
            .flatMap(() => {
                //ur Observable from HTTP call 
                return Observable 
            });
}
```

Component:-  before assigning latest value try to compare values it will avoid unnecessarily assignment

```
   this.service.poll().subscribe(
          data => {
             // if data same don't update
              if((JSON.stringify(this.models) === JSON.stringify(data) === false) ){
 this.models = data;
} 

          }
       );
```

Html code

```
< li *ngFor="let model of models ;trackBy: trackByFn " >
{{model}}
< li >
```

trackBY will stop unnecessarily rendering 
more info
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

Comment: I developed similar kind of application with observable interval and subject. one more is question  is your data will change very frequently if not than compare previous data with latest data inside component subscribe. it will reduce unnecessarily update in the model.  after developing your application try to post your experience.

Comment: Using trackBy I am able to update the screen without recreate DOM. Now I need to know what information changed to apply some style css. No I need to discover the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to combine socket.io with RxJs Observables to achieve this task

check [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/socket.io-with-rxjs-in-angular-2.0)

Comment: Do you know another way to do that without use socket.io?